# backend.php execution time exceeded while using PokeAPI, backend.php not showing in DevTools

Tags: php, json, xampp, backend, pokeapi

Im very new to making websites and Im trying to create a pokedex which is showing on a webseite and when searching for generation and type it will create a http response containing a json document which will then filter the pokemon and only show the corresponding ones. Im trying to use pokeapi to achieve this. Currently Im using xampp apache.
I've been using some ChatGPT to help me start but im stuck at the backend.

```
<br/>
<b>Fatal error</b>
:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in <b>\backend.php</b>
on line <b>19</b>
<br/>
```

```
[Error in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kMZg.png)
[backend.php not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWFb2.png)
[Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KHte.png)
```

As Im very new to this Im not very skilled in debugging/troubleshooting but I can add the code I have
Most of you will probably understand it better than me.
I think you can ignore the comments as they are in german, but please tell me if you'd like to have them in english:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pokemon web app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/frontend.css">
</head>

<body class="w3-container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#information">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#input">Input</a></li>
            <li><a href="#response">Response</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="information">
        <h2>Information</h2>
        <p>You can find infos here</p>
    </section>

    <section id="input">
        <h2>Input</h2>
        <label for="generation">Generation:</label>
        <select id="generation">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>

        <label for="firstType">First type:</label>
        <select id="firstType">
            <option value="normal">Normal</option>
            <option value="fire">Fire</option>
            <option value="water">Water</option>
            <option value="electric">Electric</option>
            <option value="grass">Grass</option>
            <option value="ice">Ice</option>
            <option value="fighting">Fighting</option>
            <option value="poison">Poison</option>
            <option value="ground">Ground</option>
            <option value="flying">Flying</option>
            <option value="psychic">Psychic</option>
            <option value="bug">Bug</option>
            <option value="rock">Rock</option>
            <option value="ghost">Ghost</option>
            <option value="dragon">Dragon</option>
            <option value="dark">Dark</option>
            <option value="steel">Steel</option>
            <option value="fairy">Fairy</option>
        </select>

        <label for="secondType">Second type:</label>
        <select id="secondType">
            <option value="none">None</option>
            <option value="normal">Normal</option>
            <option value="fire">Fire</option>
            <option value="water">Water</option>
            <option value="electric">Electric</option>
            <option value="grass">Grass</option>
            <option value="ice">Ice</option>
            <option value="fighting">Fighting</option>
            <option value="poison">Poison</option>
            <option value="ground">Ground</option>
            <option value="flying">Flying</option>
            <option value="psychic">Psychic</option>
            <option value="bug">Bug</option>
            <option value="rock">Rock</option>
            <option value="ghost">Ghost</option>
            <option value="dragon">Dragon</option>
            <option value="dark">Dark</option>
            <option value="steel">Steel</option>
            <option value="fairy">Fairy</option>
        </select>

        <button onclick="sendData()">Start search</button>
    </section>

    <section id="response">
        <h2>Response</h2>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>All Pokemon</h1>
        <ul id="pokedex"></ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick="scrollToTop()" id="scrollToTopBtn" title="Back to top">&#9650;</button>
    <script src="/js/javascript.js"></script>
    </section>

    

</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
const pokedex = document.getElementById('pokedex');
const scrollToTopBtn = document.getElementById('scrollToTopBtn');
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');

const fetchPokemon = () => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 1008; i++) {
        const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
        promises.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        const pokemon = results.map((result) => ({
            name: result.name,
            image: result.sprites['front_default'],
            type: result.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(', '),
            id: result.id
        }));
        displayPokemon(pokemon);
    });
};

const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
    console.log(pokemon);
    const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon
        .map(
            (pokeman) => `
        <li class="card">
            <img class="card-image" src="${pokeman.image}"/>
            <h2 class="card-title">${pokeman.id}. ${pokeman.name}</h2>
            <p class="card-subtitle">Type: ${pokeman.type}</p>
        </li>
    `
        )
        .join('');
    pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
};

fetchPokemon();


scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    scrollToTop();
});

//Button um nach oben zu kommen beim runterscrollen
window.onscroll = function () {
    updateScrollToTopBtnVisibility();
};

function updateScrollToTopBtnVisibility() {
    // Zeige den Button nur, wenn der Benutzer nach unten gescrollt hat
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        scrollToTopBtn.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        scrollToTopBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function scrollToTop() {
    // Scrollt die Seite nach oben, wenn der Button geklickt wird
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // Für ältere Browser
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // Für moderne Browser
}


function sendData() {
    const generation = document.getElementById('generation').value;
    const firstType = document.getElementById('firstType').value;
    const secondType = document.getElementById('secondType').value;

    const data = {
        generation: generation,
        firstType: firstType,
        secondType: secondType
    };

    fetch("../backend.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Hier kannst du die Antwort vom Backend weiter verarbeiten
        console.log(data);
        // Beispiel: Anzeigen der empfangenen Nachricht im Ausgabebereich
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data.message;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: orangered;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: rubik;
}

.container {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 54px;
}

#pokedex {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.card {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

.card:hover {
    animation: bounce 0.5s linear;
}

.card-title {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.card-subtitle {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.card-image {
    height: 180px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    20% {
        transform: translateY(-6px);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

#scrollToTopBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #007BFF;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#scrollToTopBtn:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}

/* Zeige den Button nur, wenn der Benutzer nach unten gescrollt hat */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #007BFF;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

body.scrolled-up #scrollToTopBtn {
    display: none;
}

body.scrolled-down #scrollToTopBtn {
    display: block;
}
```

and the backend

```
<?php
// Überprüfen, ob die Anfrage die erwarteten Daten enthält
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $generation = isset($_POST['generation']) ? $_POST['generation'] : null;
    $firstType = isset($_POST['firstType']) ? $_POST['firstType'] : null;
    $secondType = isset($_POST['secondType']) ? $_POST['secondType'] : null;

    // Beispiel: Pokemon-Daten von der PokeAPI abrufen
    $url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=1000";
    $pokemonData = file_get_contents($url);
    $pokemonData = json_decode($pokemonData, true);

    // Filtere Pokemon basierend auf den ausgewählten Typen
    $filteredPokemon = [];
    foreach ($pokemonData['results'] as $pokemon) {
        $pokemonDetails = file_get_contents($pokemon['url']);
        $pokemonDetails = json_decode($pokemonDetails, true);

        // Überprüfe, ob das Pokemon den ausgewählten Typen entspricht
        $hasFirstType = false;
        $hasSecondType = false;

        foreach ($pokemonDetails['types'] as $type) {
            if ($type['type']['name'] === $firstType) {
                $hasFirstType = true;
            }

            if ($type['type']['name'] === $secondType) {
                $hasSecondType = true;
            }
        }

        // Füge Pokemon zur Ergebnisliste hinzu, wenn es den ausgewählten Typen entspricht
        if ($hasFirstType && $hasSecondType) {
            $filteredPokemon[] = [
                'name' => $pokemonDetails['name'],
                'image' => $pokemonDetails['sprites']['front_default'],
                'type' => implode(', ', array_column($pokemonDetails['types'], 'type.name')),
                'id' => $pokemonDetails['id']
            ];
        }
    }

    // Beispiel: Hier wird einfach eine JSON-Antwort mit den empfangenen Daten zurückgegeben
    $response = [
        'generation' => $generation,
        'firstType' => $firstType,
        'secondType' => $secondType,
        'filteredPokemon' => $filteredPokemon,
        'message' => 'Daten erfolgreich empfangen und verarbeitet!'
    ];

    // Setzen eines Cookies (Hier wird ein einfaches Timestamp-Cookie gesetzt)
    setcookie('custom_cookie', time(), time() + 3600, '/'); // Gültig für 1 Stunde

    // Senden der JSON-Antwort
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // Falls die Anfrage nicht korrekt ist, eine Fehlermeldung senden
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Ungültige Anfrage']);
}
?>
```

I'd greatly appreciate all help.

Comment: You are aware that your PHP script calls the pokeapi.co API 1001 times, right?

Comment: Um, well it should actually be 1008 to get all the pokemon, no? Is that a problem? If im not wrong the javascript already gets all the information for the requiered search (and shows it in the frontend). Is there a possibilty to just reuse this already loaded information?

Comment: *"Is that a problem?"* Why do you think you have a timeout?

Comment: Another problem: *"People not complying with the fair use policy will have their IP address permanently banned. [...] Locally cache resources whenever you request them."* ([source](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2))

Comment: Alright, got it. This website is only a private project and will only be used for a short amount of time, but thanks for the heads-up with the caching. Coming back to the question about using the already loaded information about the pokemon, is something lke that possible?